# Pythonic ways to modify elements that contain a certain number (not just characters) in a list

Tags: python, list

I'm writing a function 'simplify' to simplify polynomials so that `simplify("2xy-yx")` can return `"xy"`, `simplify("-a+5ab+3a-c-2a")`can return `"-c+5ab"` and so on.

I am at the stage where I have merged same monomials but certain monomials will have a coefficient of `+1` or `-1`. I want to change them to just `+` or `-`. But I can't just directly delete 1 otherwise coefficients with value of `+12` or `-18` will be changed to `+2` and `-8` respectively.

For instance

```
input = '3xy+y-2x+2xy'
```

My process thus far gives me:

```
Var = ['xy', 'y', 'x']
Coe = ['+5', '+1', '-2']
```

Then I got an intermediate result: `IR = ['+5xy', '+1y', '-2x']`

My current solution:

```
[(e[0]+e[2:]) if (e[1]== '1' and e[2].isalpha() ) else e for e in IR ]
```

It seems to do the work for me for now but it looks clunky. I'm wondering if there is a cleaner and more concise way to achieve the same thing. Preferably without using Regex.

Thanks.

Edit: The code I have for this question. I'm still working on debugging it.

```
def simplify(poly):

    #If the first coefficient is positive, then I add a + for calculation later on
    if poly[0] !='-':
        poly = '+'+poly
    L = list(poly)

    #Put each monomial in a list as an element
    Temp, e = [], ''
    for i in L:
        if i != '+' and i != '-':
            e += i
        else:
            Temp.append(e)
            e = ''
            e += i

    #The last one will be left out and the first one will be None
    Temp.append(e)
    Temp.pop(0)

    #If the monomial only has a + or - in front of it, then give it a '1' so it's easier for calculation
    SortAndGiveOne = [''.join(e[0] + '1' + e[1:]) if not e[1].isdigit() else e for e in Temp]

    #Try to get letters from each element of the list
    Var = [''.join(sorted(i for i in e if i.isalpha())) for e in SortAndGiveOne]
    #Try to get coefficients from each element of the list
    Coe = [''.join(i for i in e if not i.isalpha()) for e in SortAndGiveOne]

    #Calculation of equivalent monomials
    newvar = []
    newcoe = []
    for va, co in zip(Var, Coe):
        try:
            ind = newvar.index(va)
            newcoe[ind] = str(int(newcoe[ind]) + int(co))
        except ValueError:
            newvar.append(va)
            newcoe.append(co)

    # Put the new lists together
    Put_t = list(map(lambda x,y : y + x, newvar, newcoe))

    # Add the plus sign as it will be gone if there was calculation involved.
    FinalSign = ['+'+ e if e[0] != '+' and e[0] != '-' else e for e in Put_t]

    #Delete the elements with 0 as coefficient
    Delete0 = [e for e in FinalSign if not e[1]=='0']

    #Change the +1 and -1 coefficients to + and - 
    Change1 = [(e[0]+e[2:]) if (e[1]== '1' and e[2].isalpha() ) else e for e in Delete0 ]

    #Sort the list based on length and then lexi order
    FS_sort = sorted(Change1, key = lambda s: (len(''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s))), (''.join(filter(str.isalpha, s)))))

    #Join together as a list
    JT = ''.join(FS_sort)

    #Delete leading plus sign
    if JT[0] == '+':
        JT = JT[1:]

    return JT
```

Comment: Not an answer but shouldn't everything be `+1` and `-1` instead of `+` and `-`? This makes it the same format as everything else: `[sign][count]` instead of inferring that `count`. *explicit is better than implicit*

Comment: Although I don't use the library, I strongly suspect you're re-inventinting the `sympy` wheel

Comment: @RockyLi I wish it were the way. But this is a coding question I'm doing and that's what is requested. Plus I feel like the normal way of presenting monomials is `+x` instead of `+1x`.

Comment: @roganjosh Thanks. I honestly never heard of the library. Yet again, this is just an intriguing coding question, which may have been designed to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @BowenLiu does the numbers are always single digits?

Comment: @DanielMesejo No, that's what's causing me the headache.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there could be numbers with more than two digits your code is bugged, for instance:

```
IR = ['5xy', '51y', '-2x']
result = [(e[0]+e[2:]) if (e[1]== '1' and e[2].isalpha() ) else e for e in IR ]
print(result)
```

returns:

```
['5xy', '5y', '-2x']
```

A perhaps more pythonic way will be to use a function instead:

```
def transform(e):
    multiplier = ''.join(c for c in e if c.isnumeric())
    return e[0] + e[2:] if multiplier == '1' else e


IR = ['5xy', '51y', '-2x']
result = [transform(e) for e in IR]
print(result)

IR = ['5xy', '+1y', '-2x']
result = [transform(e) for e in IR]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['5xy', '51y', '-2x']
['5xy', '+y', '-2x']
```

Note that transforms assumes the numbers are integers, but this can be easily modify to include floats (just include a check for `.`).

Comment: Sorry. I just edited my post. The list shall always have `+` or `-` as the first character, I forgot to type a plus sign. My bad. `['5xy', '51y', '-2x']` will actually appear as `['+5xy', '+51y', '-2x']`. And thanks for your answer. It is better. I will add my entire script for the problem if you care to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're only trying to modify `['5xy', '+1y', '-2x']` to `['5xy', '+y', '-2x']`, etc. In this case, I would use regex:

```
import re
newlist = [re.sub('(?<=[+-])1(?=[A-Za-z])', '', e) for e in your_list]
```

test:

```
k = ['5xy', '+1y', '-2x', '-1xy', '+11xy']
newlist = [re.sub('(?<=^[+-])1(?=[A-Za-z])', '', e) for e in k]
>>> newlist
['5xy', '+y', '-2x', '-xy', '+11xy']
```

this doesn't look much better than your solution, though.